# iOS Get Country Code not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nslocale

I am using a iphone5s which i bought from US and using the same in India for development also using the indian carrier. I am trying to get the country code with `NSLocale` but this gives me the `US`, instead of `IN`.

What should i do to make it `IN`

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];  // get the current locale.
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"country code %@",countryCode);  //US
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSLocale`'s `currentLocale` will give you information about the locale set on the device settings (Language & Region).

If you want to get the country code of the carrier instead, you'll have to use `CoreTelephony` framework:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

...

CTCarrier *carrier = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new] subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *countryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
```

A couple of things to watch for though:

> The value for this property (isoCountryCode) is nil if any of the following apply:
>
> - The device is in Airplane mode.
> - There is no SIM card in the device.
> - The device is outside of cellular service range.

[More info on the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/isoCountryCode)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3:

```
if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
        print(countryCode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## To Get Country Code

You have to Follow below method

in Appdelegate.h file

```
//#import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder  UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self getCurrentLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocatin delegate && Location Methdos

-(void)getCurrentLocation {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // To calculate loaction on 500 meters
    
    /* CLLocationDistance kilometers = 0.5 1000.0; //user will be notified when distance is changed by 40km from current distance
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kilometers; */
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self getCurrentCountry];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)aManager didFailWithError:(NSError *)anError {
    switch([anError code])
    {
        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
        {
        }
            break;
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
        }
            break;
        default:
        {
        }
            break;
    }
}

-(void)getCurrentCountry {
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Current country: %@", [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] country]);
                            NSLog(@"Current country code: %@", [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] ISOcountryCode]);
                            
                            NSLog(@"CountryCode=%@",GetContryCode);

                            SetContryCode
                            setBoolForCountryCode(YES);
                            NSLog(@"CountryCode=%@",GetContryCode);
                        }
                   }];
}
```

Comment: The problem with writing "THE BEST WAY TO DO IT" above your own answer is the same as calling your document "Document - final.xls". That being said, this is not the best way and it introduces pitfalls such as the user not granting access to Location Services and a bad "iOS 8 or not" hack.